# Python : What is the difference between matplotlib.image and scipy.misc?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

In Matplotlib and SciPy image processing tools in Python, there are a number of similar functions such as imread.
Is these libraries share common functions or uses same modules?
When working on images to read, save, etc, use Matplotlib functions or SciPy ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: both of them load a [numpy array](http://www.numpy.org/). The only difference is the methods used to load them. I would suggest using scipy's or even use [scikits-image](http://scikit-image.org/).

From [matplotlib's `imread` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread):

> Return value is a numpy.array. For grayscale images, the return array is MxN. For RGB images, the return value is MxNx3. For RGBA images the return value is MxNx4.

From [scipy's `imread` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html):

> Returns:
>   imread : ndarray
>   The array obtained by reading image from file imfile.

(By `ndarray` refeers to a `numpy.ndarray` as scipy is built on top of numpy).

Scikits-image's supports others plugins than `PIL`, such us `freeimage` or the library `tifffile`, or even `matplotlib` itself. Have a look at all the plugins/libraries supported by [scikits-image to load and save images](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html).

Comment: `scipy` also returns the array in the same format as `matplotlib`. If you follow the scipy source code for [`imread`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/misc/pilutil.py#L102), it calls a function called [`fromimage`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/misc/pilutil.py#L173), which says: "The different colour bands/channels are stored in the third dimension, such that a grey-image is MxN, an RGB-image MxNx3 and an RGBA-image MxNx4"

Comment: @tom Yep, that is exactly what I said. Both of them return the same `numpy array`. The only difference is the plugin they use to load it. Matplotlib will use PIL if available, and scipy actually uses PIL. Then is converted to a numpy array.

Comment: Yep, just thought it was worth the comment, since the snippets you have from the docs don't make it clear that you get an `MxNx{3,4}` for RGB(A) images